# jquery change event on date calculation

Tags: jquery, date

I add X number of months by Dropdown (month_number) to my start date so end date will be calculated and shown correctly:

```
 $('#start_date').change(function(){
 var months = +$('#month_number').val(); 
 var end = new Date($(this).val());
 end.setMonth(end.getMonth() + months);  
 $('#end_date').val( (end.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + end.getDate() + '/' + end.getFullYear()) ;
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8epztLv2/3/

But i want by changing the dropdown (month_number) end date is not changing !

Comment: Provide [mcve]. A demo in jsfiddle or other sandbox site would help

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/8epztLv2/2/ on mysite calculaion is working, but here not!

Comment: Please use your console to check for errors. You have missing braces in demo. These will be shown in console

Comment: Works for me as long as set #months first. Is issue that you want update if change number of months after date is set? If so you need to run same code in a change handler for the `<select>`

Comment: Yes. Update end_date if number of months is changed.

Comment: Try `$('#start_date, #month_number').change(...`. Need to validate values before calcs though

Comment: I tried this before but result shows wrong date, some dates around 2001!

Comment: Sure but you probably weren't checking that both values were valid before doing calculation of new date

Comment: can you update the code for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/8epztLv2/5/).

```
$('#start_date, #month_number').change(function() {
  var months = $('#month_number').val();
  var end = new Date($('#start_date').val());
  end.setMonth(end.getMonth() + Number(months));
  $('#end_date').val((end.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + end.getDate() + '/' + end.getFullYear());
});
```

you also have to add changing event to select element. value of end is getting from `$('#start_date').val()` instead of `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Tnx, I tried your fiddle and its worked, but on my site result shows different date ! end date starting from 2001 and months increasing X2 times by changing the months number.

Comment: Do you copy and paste like that?

Comment: Now its worked, my mistake was `var end = new Date($('#start_date').val());` . Thank you very much

Comment: There is also mistake in my answer, sorry. I have updated